# access a variable by reference from a class in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class in c++ a portion of which is below

```
class Node{
    public:
       vector<string> getNames() const;
    private:
        vector<string> names_;
};
vector<string> Node::getNames(){
    return names_;
}
```

the function getNames() passes a copy of the vector. How can i modify my class so that i can reference the vector 'by const reference' from any other class that i declare the Node object instead of passing a copy?

Comment: Sniff sniff sniff.... smells kinda homeworky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Node
{
    public:
       const vector<string>& getNames() const;

    private:
        vector<string> names_;
};

const vector<string>& Node::getNames() const
{
    return names_;
}
```

Few things:

1. getNames() is now a const method, because the Node does not logically change.
2. Return as a constant reference, so you don't make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Change the definition to

```
const vector<string>& getNames() const;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some arguments against returning references to members:

- clients of your class might hold that reference longer then your instance exists (memory corruption,)

  method and returned reference `const`-ness does not really protect you from clients using `const_cast` to remove it (logical access violation,)

  dangerous in threaded environments (race conditions.)

I would place this under [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) section.

Comment: Any client that const-casts something away is asking for crap, I don't see how that applies here. Same with string a reference. I welcome programmers to do stupid things then blame me, so I can have a good laugh.

This is not premature, this is just good principle; don't make a potentially huge copy if you don't need to.

Comment: That's true, though sometimes there are advantages to returning a copy too.